# How to switch logged user using Xamarin.auth

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, credentials, xamarin.auth

I am using Xamarin.Auth to keep the credentials saved and user logged in a Xamarin Forms application.
Now, i need to implement a "Switch logged user" but i am not figuring out how to properly do it.

Nothing about it at internet. So, if someone can explain or show how do this.

To check if has account saved:

```
IEnumerable<Account> accounts = AccountStore.Create().FindAccountsForService(InstaConstants.AppName);
```

but is always just with one account and i am testing without delete the old credentials.

Comment: Maybe start using SQLite and encrypting the contents before saving it to the DB. Or you could use a plugin like [this](https://github.com/sameerkapps/SecureStorage) (I have never tried that plugin) or use the `DependencyService` to access the protected storage APIs on each platform.

Comment: To retrieve the data from each user from SQL, i am already doing. I just don´t know how to retrieve the token from each user. I am not knowing how to do this on Xamarin.Auth

Comment: But thanks for trying to help @hvaughan3

Comment: The token that you get back from Facebook, for example?

Comment: @hvaughan3 Yes ! In my case is Instagram...but will use Facebook also.
I read that the Xamarin.Auth keep the Username and Token saved... but in my case, i just can get the Last logged...IEnumerable<Account> accounts always have just 1, that is the last...

Comment: You have to manually save the account info once the user logs in, it does not happen automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would not have a restriction to using just 1 store, you could give stores names like "MySupaApp"+iteration.ToString(); so you will iterate all users you have saved.

Another neat way is just to save your List of users into 1 account using json.

```
//im using Constants.StoreName - you know what it is..

//
//save users
//
List<MyUsers> MyList; // <==users here initially
var jsonUsers = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyList));
Account account = new Account();
account.Username = "AllMyUsers";
account.Properties.Add("users", jsonUsers);
//cleanup previous
var accounts = store.FindAccountsForService(Constants.StoreName).ToList();
accounts.ForEach(acc => store.Delete(acc, Constants.StoreName));
//save finally
await store.SaveAsync(account, Constants.StoreName);

//
//read users
//
 Account account = store.FindAccountsForService(Constants.StoreName).FirstOrDefault();
if (account == null)
            {
                //create new empty list of users
                //todo
                return false;
            }
            try
            {
            List<MyUsers> MyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyUsers>>(account.Properties["users"]);
//todo check stuff if list is valid

return true;
            }
            catch
            {
//todo
//create new empty list
//something went wrong


            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://github.com/jsauve/OAuthTwoDemo.XForms/blob/master/Android/Renderers/LoginPageRenderer.cs) example. It shows how, once the user logs in, the `Completed` event is called, you check to make sure they are logged in, and then you save the `access_token` which is stored in `eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"]`:

```
        auth.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) => {
            if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated) {
                App.Instance.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();
                // Use eventArgs.Account to do wonderful things
                App.Instance.SaveToken(eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"]);
            } else {
                // The user cancelled
            }
        };
```

*Edit: In order to save multiple accounts in the `AccountStore` you just need to provide a different `provider` value:

```
//FROM

await AccountStore.Create().SaveAsync(eventArgs.Account, "instagram"); //Saving a single general Instagram account

//TO

string someUniqueIdentifier = /* the user's User Id, an incremented number, some other identifier */

await AccountStore.Create().SaveAsync(eventArgs.Account, "instagram" + someUniqueIdentifier); //Ability to save multiple Instagram accounts, someUniqueIdentifier must change for each new account
```

Comment: I do this... you didn´t understand... the app is saving the token normally...but just the last one logged... if i do another login, its like erase the last one, because when i retrieve the accounts, always come just one. Thanks for your time buddy.

Comment: I don´t think so...because when store the Account, i read that has UserName inside... i just failing on retrieve this :(

Comment: @MCFer Would need to see the code where you save the account.

Comment: I am using                     await store.SaveAsync(account = e.Account, InstaConstants.AppName);

And it store nicely. But when i get IEnumerable<Account> accounts = AccountStore.Create().FindAccountsForService(InstaConstants.AppName); just return one value.

Comment: @MCFer Right, because you save the account info with `InstaConstants.‌​AppName`, which is the same value each time you save, it is going to just keep updating the same record. So if you have a new account you need to make the `InstaConstants.‌​AppName` unique between each account. So save it with `InstaConstants.‌​AppName + someUniqueVariable` instead for each account. And then pull each account out with the same `InstaConstants.‌​AppName + someUniqueVariable` value

Comment: But if you read the documentation, they say that the Account is retrieved with the Username + InstaConstants.‌​AppName ...Its like the Username is the UniqueVariable

Comment: @MCFer The account is retreived using what ever you saved it with. You could save the account with `"blah blah blah"` and then to retrieve it you would have to use `"blah blah blah"`. If you used `"blah blah blah 11"` to save an account and then used `"blah blah blah 22"` for another account, you have now saved 2 accounts and can pull them out using `"blah blah blah 11"` and `"blah blah blah 22"`. Just try it yourself...